# Is it possible to load xlsx with openpyxl from zipfile

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to openpyxl.load_workbook xlsx files from compressed zip file, but it doesn't work. The following code fails at openpyxl.load_workbook with "BadZipfile: File is not a zip file"

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, raw)) as z:
    for file_info in z.infolist():
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(z.open(file_info), read_only=True)
```

There is nothing wrong with the archive and the excel file in it, as if i extract it to disk then the following works:

```
with open('report.xlsx') as f:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f, read_only=True)
```

I can go with this solution and temporary extract it somewhere and load xslx, but would like to understand if it possible to load it from zipfile.

Comment: Fix your code please. This is impossible to read.

Comment: @MadPhysicist better formatted now.

Comment: You can work with in-memory objects as well but I would recommend unpacking the files.

Comment: I updated your formatting. Please study the edit for future reference when you format blocks of code. There is a toolbar button to do it for you in the editor.

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? Which line?

Comment: Try printing the value of `os.path.join(root, raw)` and checking that it's actually what you want.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, the file is fine, if it first extracts the excel i need and writes it to disk, then load_workbook passes.
I have updated my question with where exactly it raises exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `readonly=True` does not do quite what you think it does. According to the [docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html):

> Fortunately, there are two modes that enable you to read and write unlimited amounts of data with (near) constant memory consumption.

While not explicitly stated, I would assume that this involves some equivalent to a memory-mapped file (because of "constant memory consumption") and random access (because of the range of allowed operations).

Either way, setting `readonly=True` is not an indication of the fact that you only intend to read a workbook (that's all `load_workbook` can do anyway, you have to overwrite the existing one to make any "changes"). It is an indication of the fact that you want to access the file directly on disk, without loading the entire contents.

It seems pretty clear (and intuitively expected) that [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) does not provide a random-access file:

> **Note:** The file-like object is read-only and provides the following methods: `read()`, `readline()`, `readlines()`, `__iter__()`, `next()`.

The fact that `seek` is not mentioned in this list is quite telling (pun only somewhat intended).

You can get more information about the exception by splitting the offending line into two (a useful general debugging technique for nested function calls):

```
x = z.open(file_info)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(x, readonly=True)
```

You will notice that the error occurs on the second of those two lines. This is because pretty much all the Microsoft open-document formats are actually just fancy zip files. The problem is most likely that openpyxl cannot open your file in random access mode, not that it's actually an invalid zip file.

Either way, this is a bunch of very educated guesswork that leads to a simple, one-keyword-deletion solution:

#### TL;DR

Get rid of `readonly=True` when reading non-random-access data like a compressed zip entry:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(z.open(file_info))
```

#### Appendix

You should get in the habit of writing minimal programs that demonstrate your issue so that people answering your question can focus on doing their job instead of getting irritated and closing down what would otherwise be a perfectly good question. I liked your question enough to do that for you, so here is a minimal program that demonstrates your issue and requires nothing more than copy-and-paste to run:

```
import openpyxl, zipfile
from openpyxl.workbook.workbook import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
wb.active['A1'] = 12
wb.active['A2'] = 13
wb.save('report.xlsx')

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w') as z:
    z.write('report.xlsx')

with open('report.xlsx') as f:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f, read_only=True)
    print(wb.active['A1'].value)
    print(wb.active['A2'].value)

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as z:
    for file_info in z.infolist():
        x = z.open(file_info, 'r')
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(x, readonly=True)
        print(wb.active['A1'].value)
        print(wb.active['A2'].value)
```

Comment: Your point regarding putting a better formatted questions, accompanied by demo code if possible, is definitely taken.